# How to go from a Model base to derived class in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

Assuming a simple set of inherited Model classes, like this:

```
class BaseObject(models.Model): 
    some_field = models.SomeField(...)

class AwesomeObject(BaseObject): 
    awesome_field = models.AwesomeField(...)

class ExcellentObject(BaseObject): 
    excellent_field = models.ExcellentField(...)
```

and a query that looks like this:

```
found_objects = BaseObject.objects.filter(some_field='bogus')
```

What's the best way to take each `found` object and turn it back into it's derived class?  The code I'm using now is like this:

```
for found in found_objects:
    if hasattr(found, 'awesomeobject'): 
        ProcessAwesome(found.awesomeobject)
    elif hasattr(found, 'excellentobject'): 
        ProcessExcellent(found.excellentobject):
```

But, it feels like this is an abuse of "hasattr".  Is there a better way to do this without creating an explicit "type" field on the base class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's the best way that I know of. Unfortunately, inheritance is a little clunky in this regard. Multiple table inheritance is basically just a one-to-one relationship between the parent model and the extra fields the child adds, which is why that `hasattr` trick works. You can think of each of those as a `OneToOneField` attribute on your parent model. When you think of it that way, Django has no way of knowing which child to return or even if to return a child, so you have to handle that logic yourself:

I tend to create a method on the parent such as `get_child`, which simply cycles through the attributes and returns the one that pops:

```
class BaseObject(models.Model):
    some_field = models.SomeField(...)

    def get_child(self):
        if hasattr(self, 'awesomeobject'): 
            return ProcessAwesome(found.awesomeobject)
        elif hasattr(self, 'excellentobject'): 
            return ProcessExcellent(found.excellentobject):
        else:
            return None
```

At least then, you can just call `found.get_child()`, and maybe forget about the hackery that gets you there.

Comment: Nah.. Better look at django-polymorphic ;-)

Answer (score 6):

For this specific problem, there is [django-polymorphic](https://github.com/chrisglass/django_polymorphic). It works by using the content type framework in Django to store the model ID which the derived table points to. When you evaluate the queryset, it will upcast all models their specific type.

You'll get:

```
>>> BaseProject.objects.all()
[ <AwesomeObject>, <ExcellentObject>, <BaseObject>, <AwesomeObject> ]
```

Comment: Ok I can see that you can use manager methods to get derived-class instances. How about the author's question of going from a parent model instance to a derived model instance? Does django-polymorphic offer a solution for that as well?

Comment: Yes it does, the individual model has a `get_real_instance()` method too. Most of the time you don't need it, because the manager already gives the derived models. Besides, it also avoids the N-query problem by fetching multiple objects of the same type in a single query.

Answer (score 4):

Going from a base class to a derived class is generally a sign of bad design in a program. The method you propose, using `hasattr`, can be a serious problem. I'll show you:

```
# defined in some open source library
class MyObject(object):
    def what_is_derived(self):
        if hasattr(self, 'derived1'):
            return 'derived1'
        elif hasattr(self, 'derived2'):
            return 'derived2'
        else:
            return 'base'
```

Let's pretend that classes `Derived1` and `Derived2` are defined in that same library. Now, you want to use the features of `MyObject`, so you derive from it in your own code.

```
# defined in your own code
class MyBetterObject(MyObject):
    pass

better_object = MyBetterObject()
better_object.what_is_derived() # prints 'base'
```

The whole point of polymorphism is that you can have many derived classes without the base class having to change. By making the base class aware of all of it's derived classes, you severely reduce the usefulness of such a class. You can't create a derived class without changing the base class.

Either you want to work with a derived class, or you don't care what the specific class is and all you need are the properties/methods of the base class. It is the same in all OOP languages. There are facilities for finding out what the derived class is, but usually it's a bad idea.

From a django models perspective, I usually use inheritance in such a way:

```
class Address(models.Model):
    # fields...

class Person(Address):
    # fields...

class Business(Address):
    # fields...

Address.objects.all() # find all addresses for whatever reason
Person.objects.all() # im only interested in people
Business.objects.all() # need to work with businesses

# need to show all addresses in a postcode, and what type of address they are?
businesses = Business.objects.filter(postcode='90210')
people = Person.objects.filter(postcode='90210')
# use the address properties on both
```

Deeply nested inheritance chains with django models are awkward. They are also pretty unnecessary in most cases. Instead of polluting your base class with `hasattr` checks, define a helper method which is capable of querying the required derived classes if such a thing is called for. Just don't define it on the Base class.

Comment: "Going from a base class to a derived class is generally a sign of bad design in a program." What nonsense. Going from a base class to a derived class is called polymorphism and is fundamental to object-orientation. It's just that in this specific case it doesn't work without a hack.

Comment: @jwg did you read the rest of what I wrote, or only focus on that particular sentence? Polymorphism works when you have methods/attributes common across the tree. If you need derived attributes, then you should be working with the derived model, not the base model. Django multi-table model inheritance is a poor approximation of polymorphism, and in my view, (nearly) all django inheritance should be done with abstract bases.

Comment: And.. just so it's clear. "Going from a base class to a derived class is generally a sign of bad design in a program." - when downcasting to a derived class. Using polymorphism to dynamically dispatch to a subclass method or attribute is fine.

Answer (score 2):

I use introspection ;

```
class Base(models.Model):
[ we have some unique 'key' attribute ]
class_name = models.CharField(..., editable=False)

def get_base(self):
    if self.__class__ == Base:
        return self
    # if we are not an instance of Base we 'go up'
    return Base.objects.get(key=self.key)

def get_specific(self):
    if self.__class__ != Base:
        return self
    # if we are an instance of Base we find the specific class
    class_type = getattr(sys.modules["project.app.models"],
        self.class_name)
    return class_type.objects.get(key=self.key)
```

You need some factory to create the specific classes so you are sure to correctly save str(self.**class**) in class_name

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `InheritanceQuerySet` from `django-model-utils` in case you want to explicitly state which queries to affect, like this:

```
from model_utils.managers import InheritanceQuerySet

class UserManager([...]):

    def get_queryset(self):
        return InheritanceQuerySet(self.model).select_subclasses()
```

(code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/25108201)