# Automatically downcast to subclass using django-model-utils

Tags: python, django, django-models, multiple-inheritance

I have multiple user models .. all inheriting  a Base model with a custom manager

### models.py

```
class BaseUser(models.Model):
    [...]

    objects = UserManager()


class StaffUser(BaseUser):
    [...]

class Customer(BaseUser):
    [...]
```

### managers.py

```
from model_utils.managers import InheritanceManager

class UserManager(..., InheritanceManager):
    [...]
```

By inheriting the InheritanceManager from django-model-utils, I can do automatic downcasting for inherited models. So for example, if I have 3 objects, one of each user type:

```
user = BaseUser.objects.select_subclasses()

[Customer: customer@example.com, BaseUser: studio@example.com, StaffUser: staff@example.com]
```

To do that, I had to explicitly call `.select_subclasses()`,

But I want to do the downcasting automatically without having to call `.select_subclasses()`

So I tried:

class UserManager(..., InheritanceManager):

```
    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = super(UserManager, self).get_queryset()
        return queryset.get_subclass(*args, **kwargs)
```

But now when I try to use:

```
user = EmailUser.objects.all()
```

I get this:

```
MultipleObjectsReturned: get() returned more than one BaseUser -- it returned 3!
```

Is it possible to do automatic downcasting for inherited models using django-model-utils?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out!

### managers.py

```
from model_utils.managers import InheritanceQuerySet

class UserManager([...]):

    def get_queryset(self):
        return InheritanceQuerySet(self.model).select_subclasses()
```

I didn't have to inherit `InheritanceManager`, instead use the `InheritanceQuerySet`.