# Inheritance in Django: Make parent class fall back to child method

Tags: python, django, inheritance

Tl;Dr: Circumvent that parents can not call child methods in python (I guess)

Consider the following (simplified) django models were `MaterialInstance` and `BookInstance` both inherit `Item`.

```
class Item(models.Model):
    """Represents an item that is physically in the library"""


    label = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)

    @property
    def description(self) -> str:
        raise NotImplementedError

class BookInstance(Item):
    """Represents a copy of a book that is physically in the library"""

    @property
    def description(self) -> str:
        return str(self.book)

    book = models.ForeignKey('Book', on_delete=models.RESTRICT)

class MaterialInstance(Item):
    """Represents a instance of a material that is physically in the library"""

    @property
    def description(self) -> str:
        return str(self.material)

    material = models.ForeignKey('Material', on_delete=models.RESTRICT, null=True)
```

I want to show all items (books AND material instances) in one table. One row should be a description (either the book title or the material name). It would be nice to use the following template (but this raises a `NotImplementedError` as the parent class does not try to call child methods. Any suggestions for a clever design that circumvents this problem?

```
    <table>
        <tr>
        <th>Label</th>
        <th>Description</th>
    
        </tr>
        {% for item in item_list %}
            <tr>{{ item.label }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.description }}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
```

The final thing should look something like this

| Label | Description |
| --- | --- |
| B1 | A Boring Book Title |
| B2 | A Boring Book Title |
| M1 | Stapler |
| M2 | Torch |
| B3 | Different Book Title |

Comment: One solution would be to add a field to the parent class called 'description.' Another solution would be to use a package like [django-polymorphic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6310865/how-to-go-from-a-model-base-to-derived-class-in-django/6311767).

Comment: Django polymorphic was exactly what i was looking for as descriptions were different for books and materials. Thanks!